# Cisco VPN client - How to block Odd numbered addresses with ACL (Extended ACL)?

Tags: cisco, access-control-list

So I am trying to configure a VPN client on cisco packet tracer but I am having some issues with configuring the ACL. In my task I am trying to create a VPN tunnel between R4 and R2. I am trying to Block the odd numbered IP addresses in R2 LAN from using the VPN tunnel. How am I meant to write this access list? I will attach an image to better represent this.

[VPN diagram below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsXPY.png)

Comment: It is always a good idea to obfuscate specific site details on slack.-- I would suggest redesigning your network so that addresses you want to block are grouped together in some form. Even something simple like 192.168.1.xxx  and 192.168.2.xxx.  If you are stuck with a /24 at each site for some reason, 192.168.1.0xx for allowed hosts and then block 192.168.1.1xx.

Comment: @RowanHawkins well I cant use those IP addresses because it was a given task with those IP specifically